# How use image asset as Icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to use image asset for `AnimatedIconItem` in [big_button_example.dart](https://github.com/Frezyx/animated_icon_button/blob/master/example/lib/big_button_example.dart) file in `animated_icon_button` flutter library. You can find the library on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_icon_button). `SimpleIcons` is used for Icon. Original code is :

```
AnimatedIconItem(
   icon: Icon(SimpleIcons.nasa, color: color),
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
),
```

I want to use image asset for icon variable. I tried these :

```
icon: ImageIcon(
   AssetImage("images/icon.png"),
   color: Color(0xFF3A5A98),
),
```

---

```
icon: Image.asset('assets/icon.png'),
```

---

```
icon: IconButton(
   icon: Image.asset('assets/icon.png'),
),
```

But always I got error like `The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Icon'`. How can I use image for Icon?

Comment: I found that it just take `Icon` type data.  and `Icon` can have only `IconData`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Try this:

    class Menu {
        const Menu({this.icon, this.title});
        final ImageIcon icon;
        final String title;
    } 

    const List<Menu> menus = const <Menu>[  
    const Menu(
            title: 'menu_icon_1',
            icon:ImageIcon(
            AssetImage('assets/menu/11.png')
            ),
          ),
       ];
```

Comment: It would be good if you would provide a brief summary of what the code does and how it solves the issue.